# How to search and delete string in php

Tags: php, xml, regex

I am attempting to use an RSS feed from Twitter (the ones that will be gone a year from now) with Feedburner but a line of code in the xml is causing a parsing error in feedburner. I think it's

> xmlns:twitter="http://api.twitter.com"

I am looking for a way to give this information to feedburner in a way that it likes: namely php including the contents of the RSS xml page in an xml on my own site (with the offending string removed). Including the xml contents is a piece of cake - all I need is a piece of code to say iff string fragment ==  `xmlns:twitter="http://api.twitter.com"`  then string frament = "".

Anybody any idea of the syntax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
str_replace('xmlns:twitter="http://api.twitter.com"', '', $string);
```

Also, you can try to [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) `http://api.twitter.com`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use **preg_replace** function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

```
<?php
$string = 'string to be searched';
$pattern = 'a particular pattern';
$replacement = ''; //deletion
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```